# Problem in table

Tags: export, list-manipulation, difference-equations, differentials, output-formatting

```
NDSolve[{t,Evaluate[{ode}\.Sol]},{t,0,10,1}]//TableForm
```

After executing this with appropriate equations I get solution in the tabular form but when I try to export this to excel it appears with brackets. How do I remove those brackets?

Comment: `TableForm` (and all the `*Form` wrappers) should be used for display only, and not for further computation. Try removing it before exporting.

Comment: `(result = 
   NDSolve[{t, Evaluate[{ode} \.Sol]}, {t, 0, 10, 1}]) // TableForm` then export `result`

Comment: The problem still persists

Comment: The problem is still existing

Comment: BTW, `\.` does not have a built-in meaning.

Answer (score 0):

```
Reap[NDSolve[{y'[x] == y[x] Cos[x + y[x]], y[0] == 1}, y, {x, 0, 1}, 
    StepMonitor :> Sow[{x, y[x]}]]][[2, 1]] // TableForm

\!\(
TagBox[GridBox[{
{"0.00009909606535016074`", "1.0000535319703938`"},
{"0.00019819213070032147`", "1.0001070540762556`"},
{"0.003581745354996745`", "1.0019287482920178`"},
{"0.006965298579293169`", "1.003738849393516`"},
{"0.010348851803589592`", "1.0055372671423326`"},
{"0.021167766710639673`", "1.0112083455276724`"},
{"0.029862641912325277`", "1.0156768623031491`"},
{"0.038557517114010884`", "1.0200644235423932`"},
{"0.04725239231569649`", "1.024369684413221`"},
{"0.05594726751738209`", "1.0285913615412645`"},
{"0.0733370179207533`", "1.0367791243987443`"},
{"0.0907267683241245`", "1.0446186419122474`"},
{"0.10811651872749571`", "1.0521018317833108`"},
{"0.1255062691308669`", "1.0592215702424477`"},
{"0.1428960195342381`", "1.065971717107212`"},
{"0.1835588067785299`", "1.080285782216985`"},
{"0.21547040619170865`", "1.0900546859017402`"},
{"0.24738200560488743`", "1.098523311626691`"},
{"0.27929360501806616`", "1.105690642600577`"},
{"0.31120520443124494`", "1.1115644173551147`"},
{"0.3374815894884578`", "1.1154407013340815`"},
{"0.36375797454567066`", "1.1184627355609276`"},
{"0.3900343596028835`", "1.1206457038812567`"},
{"0.4163107446600964`", "1.1220072947929343`"},
{"0.44258712971730924`", "1.1225673665130875`"},
{"0.48343421327054725`", "1.1218981262172334`"},
{"0.5242812968237853`", "1.119433428623533`"},
{"0.5562242679699305`", "1.1163160323415637`"},
{"0.5881672391160758`", "1.1122058167628923`"},
{"0.6201102102622211`", "1.1071509771467047`"},
{"0.6520531814083664`", "1.1012002031945898`"},
{"0.6839961525545117`", "1.0944022121379378`"},
{"0.715939123700657`", "1.0868053892969587`"},
{"0.7699228634640567`", "1.0722840254078878`"},
{"0.8239066032274563`", "1.0558413333402281`"},
{"0.877890342990856`", "1.0376919384457102`"},
{"0.9318740827542557`", "1.0180391180053738`"},
{"0.9659370413771279`", "1.00495160638102`"},
{"1.`", "0.9913872601599517`"}
},
GridBoxAlignment->{"Columns" -> {{Left}}, "Rows" -> {{Baseline}}},
GridBoxSpacings->{"Columns" -> {
Offset[0.27999999999999997`], {
Offset[2.0999999999999996`]}, 
Offset[0.27999999999999997`]}, "Rows" -> {
Offset[0.2], {
Offset[0.4]}, 
Offset[0.2]}}],
Function[BoxForm`e$, 
TableForm[BoxForm`e$]]]\)
```